# Resize An Existing Rectangle On Mouse Hover

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, svg-rect

I tried to follow a tutorial and finally came to a solution, almost. Here's the link for stackblitz - [Resize SVG Rectangle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-draw-app-minapa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcanvas%2Fcanvas.component.ts)

So here's the scenario, a rectangle is drawn using SVG with default perimeters that's working fine. My requirement is to resize the existing rectangle when I hover the mouse on it and if I click in any other section rather than the rectangle, then it should be drawn from scratch. So right now, whatever I do, it starts the drawing from scratch rather than resizing the existing one.

For a reference, this is what I am trying for resizing only: [Resize Rectangle](https://ibb.co/M1MzLCM)

So these are the events that are attached to the svg element:

```
//This section starts drawing rectangle from scratch
startDrawing(evt: MouseEvent) {
    this.createdShape = {
      type: this.shapeType,
      x: evt.offsetX,
      y: evt.offsetY,
      w: 0,
      h: 0,
  };

  this.shapesToDraw.fill(this.createdShape); //This fills with the created shape
}

//This does the resizing but only when I start drawing a rectangle from scratch, doesn't imply resizing for existing rectangle
keepDrawing(evt: MouseEvent) {
   this.createdShape.w = evt.offsetX - this.createdShape.x;
   this.createdShape.h = evt.offsetY - this.createdShape.y;
}

//This stops drawing and sets **createdShape** to null
stopDrawing() {
   this.createdShape = null;
}
```

I am thinking to check if there are any certain conditions to check for resizing as follows:

```
private resizeConMeet(evt: MouseEvent) {
    
}
```

But I am not sure if there's any way I can do so? Would expect a suggestion or guidance to make it work.

Comment: I don't understand which part is not working, bit confusing question.

Comment: `By default, there's a rectangle. What I want, when I take the mouse on the existing rectangle, it should resize rather creating a new rectangle. On the other hand, if I click on other section rather than the existing rectangle, it should be created from scratch` - Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work :)

So, thanks to the StackBlitz, I could adapt the code.

The main ideas :

- When you start drawing, try to use the previous shape if

  - `this.createdShape.x < evt.x < this.createdShape.x + w`
  - `this.createdShape.y < evt.y < this.createdShape.y + h`
- This means that you should not erase the previous shape (`this.createdShape = null`) when you stop drawing
- But this will create a bug because it will continue editing the shape when the mouse moves. Solve this by adding a variable (`isDrawing`) that you set to `true` when you start drawing and set to `false` when you stop drawing. Use this variable to prevent redrawing the rectangle when you are not drawing

Please try to do it by yourself. Here is [my version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-draw-app-gwube9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcanvas%2Fcanvas.component.ts)

Comment: With the logic above (The comparison one), you are checking if the created shape's x and y coordinates doesn't change, then start resizing the existing one. I guess, this is what you have one. Nice one!